# How to create a 1:n relationship with hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

I am using hibernate to represent a database with the three major Entities User, Project and Comment. User and Project inherit from Base class. The Project also holds an unlimited amount of comments.
In the POJO i tried to represent the collection of comments associated by a project by with a `List<Comment>`.

My major problem is, when i i go and take a project which holds a number of comment references within the list java will throw an IllegalArgumentException saying, that it cant access the id field of comment, as it only gets an ArrayList.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field com.project.objects.Comment.id to java.util.ArrayList
```

My classes are as followed - without Constructor/Setter/Getter as these are plain simple:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Base {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private String longDesc;
    @Column
    private String briefDesc;
    @Column
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)
    private List<String> goals;
    @Column
    private String picture;
    @Column
    private int cType;
```

```
@Entity(name = "Project")
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project extends Base {
    @Column
    private String start;
    @Column
    private String end;
    @Column
    private String manager;
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=Comment.class)
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Comment.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "comment_id")
    private List<Comment> comments;
```

```
@Entity(name = "Comment")
@Table(name = "comment")
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @Column(name="comment_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String comment;
    @Column
    private int rating;
    @Column
    private int pcuser;
    @Column
    private int cType;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 1:N association is wrong, as it is actually a N:1 right now. The correct would be:

```
Entity(name = "Project")
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project extends Base {
    @Column
    private String start;
    @Column
    private String end;
    @Column
    private String manager;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Comment> comments;
```

And in your `Comment` class:

```
@Entity(name = "Comment")
@Table(name = "comment")
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @Column(name="comment_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String comment;
    @Column
    private int rating;
    @Column
    private int pcuser;
    @Column
    private int cType;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_project", nullable = false)
    private Project project;
    // THIS is the required and obrigatory mapping that you forgot.
    // It's the foreing key itself
```

#### Disclaimer

I've never actually used Hibernate with inheritance before (usually, it's desnecessarily complex and also inefficient for a relational database) but check `https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance` and `https://marcin-chwedczuk.github.io/mapping-inheritance-in-hibernate` for more information.

Comment: The Inheritance works as expected and this was the fix for my problem - thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `@ManyToOne` annotation for `comments` but it should be `@OneToMany`.

In order to use `@OneToMany` you would have to have a column called something like `project_id` in the `comment` table, which you would reference from the `@OneToMany` field. Do you have that?

If not, how are you linking comments to projects in your database?

By the way, it's really easy to create poorly-performing systems with Hibernate, because it tends to obscure the cost of hitting the database. You've said that there can be any number of comments associated with a project. Do you *really* want to load them *all* every time the code loads a project? Let's say you just want a list of projects, for example to populate a selection list. Simply loading that list will also load every comment in the system, even though you don't actually need them.

Answer (score 0):

Comment is an entity and should not be used with the @ElementCollection inside the Project entity.

Your relationship is a project to many comments. @OneToMany